# My python code for extracting nucleotide sequences based on tblastn hits is too slow

Tags: python, xml

I did multiple query tblastn search using standalone blast on my local database from a python script and the output is a large XML file. I needed to parse the output taking only the top four hits because some queries returns more than four hits. But since the output is given as amino acids sequence alignment records, it is important to parse the high scoring pairs of the hit subject of the original nucleotide sequences where the hsps start and end, for each tblastn record in a file.

So I have this code but it is painfully slow and given the amount of data it can take even more than a month to finish what it is doing. Can somebody help me with an improved alternative?

```
> from Bio import SeqIO 
> from Bio.Blast import NCBIXML
> 
> infile_path = '/home/edson/ungulate/ungulate.fa'    # this is a file
> which contain unaligned nucleotide sequences  outfile_path =
> '/home/edson/ungulate/tblastn_result.fa'
> 
> for seq_record in SeqIO.parse(infile_path, 'fasta'):
>     flag = seq_record.description            # a flag is sequence identifier in a fasta file format

      with open(outfile_path, 'a') as outfile:
          with open('/home/edson/ungulate/tblastn_result.xml') as tblastn_file:
             tblastn_records = NCBIXML.parse(tblastn_file)
             for tblastn_record in tblastn_records:
                 for alignment in tblastn_record.alignments[:4]:
                     for hsp in alignment.hsps:
                         if flag in alignment.title:         
                          # this cross check if sequence identifier is present in an XML file
>                            sub_record = seq_record.seq[hsp.sbjct_start:hsp.sbjct_end] 
                             # this takes sequences in an infile path and slice them based on tblastn output
>                            outfile.write('>' + seq_record.description + '\n')
>                            outfile.write(str(sub_record + '\n'))
```

Thanks.

Comment: Why the greater-than signs? Did you hit the quote button, then the code button?

Comment: What are the `len` for `tblastn` and `alignment.hsps` (typical)? What part of your program is slow?

Comment: The loop in which you assign `flag` overwrites the old value of `flag` on every iteration after the first. Do you want a list of flags? Or will the `for` loop only have one iteration?

Comment: Yes, what? Yes, you wanted a list? Yes, there will only be one iteration?

Comment: @goncalopp, Basically the alignments in the records are of differing lengths depending on where the hsps begin and end. I have no idea what is causing it to be slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two obvious bottlenecks - for *each* iteration of the outer loop, you

1. reopen `outfile`
2. reopen **and** re-parse `tblastn_file`

Just moving these operations outside of the outer loop should yield some noticeable perf improvement (if you have more than one iteration of the outer loop, of course).

Another possible improvement: you test for `flag in alignment.title` on each iteration over ̀`alignment.hsps`. This test will be constant for all `hsps` for a same `hsps` so better to put it before, ie:

```
for alignment in tblastn_record.alignments[:4]:
    if flag in alignment.title:  
        for hsp in alignment.hsps:
           # etc...
```